# Using asynchrnous operations related on state of another object

Tags: typescript, vue.js, async-await, vuex

I'm facing a problem with asynchronous operations in Vue. As a C# developer I find async-await pattern more obvious than in js/ts especially with Vue.

I have 2 components (non Vuex approach):

```
// App.vue
// ...
async beforeCreated() {
  console.log('connecting')
  await WebSocket.connect(...)
  console.log('connected')
}
```

```
// ChildComponent.vue
// ...
async mounted() {
  console.log('invoking')
  await WebSocket.Invoke(...)
  console.log('invoked')
}
```

What I get is

```
1. connecting
2. invoking
3. invoked
4. connected
```

So I'm not connected and Invoke fails. I've tried do something like this with Vuex but with no luck. Connecting to WebSocket part is simple: use Action and Mutation but the 'Invoking' part is not obvious.

I've tried to execute something like this but getting `undefined`

```
// ChildComponent.vue
// ...
async mounted() {
  await this.$store.state.moduleA.webSocket.Invoke(...) // moduleA is defined but webSocket is not
}
```

Moreover using Vuex's mutations and actions are illogical since I'm not changing state of any object - just invoking some server-side procedure.

How I should implement this in properly? I'm really stuck with this. I'm using TypeScript if this information is relevant somehow.

---

Vue code:

App.vue

```
<template>
      <child-component />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import ChildComponent from './components/ChildComponent.vue';

export default Vue.extend({
  components: { ChildComponent },
  name: 'App',
  async beforeCreate()  {
    await this.$WebSocket.connect(...)
  }
});
</script>
```

ChildComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <div>something</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'ChildComponent',
  async mounted() : Promise<void> {
    await this.$WebSocket.Invoke(...)
  },
})
</script>
```

Comment: You didn't show the whole case. You should wait for a parent to complete actions before rendering a child. You could expect `async` to affect something if the framework had a specific support for promises in lifecycle hooks - but it doesn't. Is it Vue 2? In Vue 3 you could use `async setup` for this.

Comment: @EstusFlask Added. Please take a look. It's Vue 2 but I really don;t care about version. UI framework for Vue2 was more interesting for me that the reason why I choose this one :D

Comment: In your case it should be `<child-component v-if="initialized" />` where initialized is a bool. If you consider V3 take a look at asynchronous components and suspense, they fit this case

Answer (score 0):

The only problem here is in `async/await` misundestanding. It's just an syntax sugar on Promises, so your code equals this.

```
beforeCreated() {
  console.log('connecting')
  WebSocket.connect(...).then(() => {
    console.log('connected')
  });
}
```

So the `beforeCreate` hook exits on `await` line and Vue instance is going down on next hooks. So in this case you should not rely on Vue hooks. Instead, use Websocket [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/open_event)

```
async beforeCreated() {
  Websocket.on('open', () => {
    this.websocketIsOpened = true; // should present in data()
  });
  await WebSocket.connect(...)
},
template: `
...
<ChildComponent v-if="websocketIsOpened" />
or 
<ChildComponent v-bind="websocketIsOpened" />
```

In second variant you probably need an [immediate watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch) in child component on this prop to call `Invoke` method